# how to set the parameter batch_dims in tf.gather_nd tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

example:

```
a=tf.constant([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]])
b=[[1]]
c=tf.gather_nd(a,b,batch_dims=0)
```

I want to get the result:

```
c=[[4,5,6],[10,11,12]]
```

but the tensorflow gives me

```
c=[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
```

I know we can set b=[[0,1],[1,1]] to get the result, but when the tensor 'a' has a large batch size with shape [batch, x,y], how can i simply set the parameters to get a[:,b].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the following code:

```
a=tf.constant([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]])
b=1
c=a[:,b,:]
```

**Update:** Instead of `tf.gather_nd` you could use `tf.gather` where along with `batch_dims=0` you can specify the `axis=1`.

```
b = [1]  # or [[1]]     
c=tf.gather(a,b,axis=1)  # argument batch_dims=0 is default value
```

Output:

```
print(c.numpy())
[[ 4  5  6]
 [10 11 12]]
```

Comment: Please check out the updated answer which i think the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have TF 2.0 to try it out, but according to documentation, you should get what you want with:

```
b=[[1], [1]]
c=tf.gather_nd(a,b,batch_dims=1)
```

if you are lucky it might also work to broadcast with

```
b=[[1]]
```

Comment: I run the code, but get the folloing error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  ValueError: batch_dims = 1 must be less than rank(params) = 1

Comment: @wangwei are you using TF 2.0?? It works fine when i run it with tf 2.0.. with b =[[1], [1]].

Comment: I don't understand the effect of the parameter batch_dims

Comment: batch_dims=N informs TF that the first N dimensions of the tensor are batch dimensions (usually just one), so instead of [[0,x0],[1,x1],...,[n-1,x_(n-1)]] you don't have to bother enumerate on that dimension, i.e. you could write [[x0],[x1],...,[x_(n-1)]]. In your case, x0=x1=...=1